# Servlet receives empty request from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, request

I have a javascript program that tries to send an AJAX request to a Java HTTPServlet. The servlet is listening to a specified pattern "/users" and returns an XML. My problem is that when the request is sent to the servlet, the request body is empty. I know I'm not using any cross-domain stuff (everything resides in the same domain running off the same server). Here's what my AJAX code looks like:

```
    var data = ($"form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
         url : "../users",
         data : data,
         dataType : "xml",
         type : "PUT",
         success : function(data){ ... },
         error : function(data){ ... }
    });
```

The serialized form returns 
username="username"&password=&email=

and my servlet

```
    @Override
    public void onPut(HTTPServletRequest req, HTTPServletResponse resp){
         String username = req.getParameter("username");
         ...
    }
```

username ends up being null

I know the request is at least being sent because I get a response from the servlet, but when I run the program a debugger, in the servlet, the incoming parameters from the request body are always empty.

[update]
When I modified the code to send a JSON or XML body over PUT, the request seemed to process. It's weird that serialized forms don't seem to go through unless I'm using POST or GET.

Answer (score 0):

`serialize` is a method.

```
$.ajax({
     url : "../users",
     data : $("#form").serialize(),
     dataType : "xml",
     type : "PUT",
     success : function(data){ ... },
     error : function(data){ ... }
});
```

Then in your servlet, try to change your code as follow:

```
String username = req.getParameterValues("username");
```

Comment: You're right, I changed it and the servlet still received an empty set of request parameters.

Comment: OK, I added some other information in the servlet-side.

Comment: What's the difference between `req.getParameterValues()` and `req.getParameter()`